# Mysql Query optimisation

Tags: mysql

Hi need some help with a mysql query

my data is like so

```
Table base_status

| id | order_id | status | dt_added |
-------------------------------------
| 1  | 123      | xyz    | date3    |
| 2  | 123      | abc    | date2    |
| 3  | 123      | pqr    | date1    |
```

I'm trying to get output as such

```
| order_id | xyz_date | abc_date | pqr_date |
-------------------------------------------
| 123      | date3    | date2    | date3    |
```

MySQL query:

```
select BS.order_id, XYZ.dt_added AS xyz_date, 
       ABC.dt_added AS abc_date, PQR.dt_added AS pqr_date,
from base_status BS
LEFT JOIN base_status XYZ ON BS.order_id=TAS.order_id and TAS.status='xyz'
LEFT JOIN base_status ABC ON BS.order_id=TAS.order_id and TAS.status='abc'
LEFT JOIN base_status PQR ON BS.order_id=PQR.order_id and PQR.status='pqr'
....
```

**My question**: How can I avoid the 3 left joins. Is there anything to do same thing with only a single join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way not to query the same table multiple times is to use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) to group the three dates, and [FIELD](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php) to keep the entry order :

```
SELECT order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(dt_added) AS "xyz_date,abc_date,pqr_date "
FROM base_status
WHERE status IN ('xyz', 'abc', 'pqr')
GROUP BY order_id
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'xyz', 'abc', 'pqr')
```

Granted, the result will be slightly different from what you're trying to achieve :

```
| order_id | xyz_date,abc_date,pqr_date |
-----------------------------------------
| 123      | date3,date2,date1          |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a group_concat (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

but this solution need post-processing to split the values

```
SELECT order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(status), GROUP_CONCAT(dt_added) FROM     base_status GROUP BY order_id
```

the Cells will look like `pqr, abc, xyz` and `date1, date2, date2`

Then you could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to split it up again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(status), GROUP_CONCAT(dt_added)
FROM
    base_status
GROUP BY
    order_id
```

To get output like this

```
| order_id | status        | dt_added              |
----------------------------------------------------
| 123      | xyz, abc, pqr | date3, date2, date1   |
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have more than 3 dates,dynamic pivot is the way to go

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(case when dt_added = ''',
      dt_added ,
      ''' then dt_added  end) AS ',
      CONCAT(status,'_','date')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from base_status;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT order_id, ', @sql, ' from base_status
group by order_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6be0/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregrate function combined with the IF statement to bring back the columns as you specify:-

```
SELECT order_id,
        MAX(IF(status = 'xyz', dt_added, NULL)) AS xyz_date,
        MAX(IF(status = 'abc', dt_added, NULL)) AS abc_date,
        MAX(IF(status = 'pqr', dt_added, NULL)) AS pqr_date
FROM base_status 
GROUP BY order_id
```

However I suspect that if properly indexed the 3 table join should perform fine.